# Java - break in while loop does not work

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have a code like this

```
while(setIterator.hasNext()){
    String key = setIterator.next();

    if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("location_id")){
        containlocationid = true;

        int id_key = Integer.parseInt(requestMap.get(key));

        if(player.isLocationExists(id_key) == true){
            player.setlocationID(Integer.parseInt(requestMap.get(key)));
            responseOut.println("NOW WILL NOT BREAK AND SAVE");
        }else{
            responseOut.println("NOW WILL BREAK AND NO SAVE");
            break;
        }
    }else if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
        player.setName(requestMap.get(key));
        responseOut.println("this is inside NAME");
    }else if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
        player.setDescription(requestMap.get(key));
        responseOut.println("this is inside DESCRIPTION");
    }
}
```

When get boolean "false", the while loop will break and print "NOW WILL BREAK AND NO SAVE". But now i get a result like this

```
this is inside NAME <- this will not print out after break while loop
this is inside DESCRIPTION <- this will not print out after break while loop
NOW WILL BREAK AND NO SAVE
```

means that it is successful to save and the break does not work.I tried the "Outer:" & "break Outer;" function but failed too.

hope you understand what im talking, Please help, thanks!

Comment: Please do a proper indentation

Comment: It seems that your set contains something like "name", "description" and "location_id", in that order. And the isLocationExists() method returns false

Comment: Is it that you are getting the keys in the order of "name", "description" and then "location_id". In this case, I guess the output that is getting printed is correct

Comment: From the output, it looks like the break is working fine - your iterator returns `name`, `description` & `location_id` then `player.isLocationExists(id_key)` returns `false` and the loop breaks

Comment: yup.. i have no idea. i spent whole day to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NOW WILL BREAK AND NO SAVE

is the last statement in your output. No other statement is printed after that, which clearly indicates that while loop has been terminated after executing the `else` clause.
Loop termination will take place only because of two reasons over here:

- while loop condition i.e. `setIterator.hasNext()` returned `false`
- `break` statement got executed (which looks more probable to me)

Also you can replace `if(player.isLocationExists(id_key) == true)` simply with `if(player.isLocationExists(id_key))`

Comment: or the break will only effect the "if" statement, that's why the while loop still continue looping?

Comment: @LcWei : You must read about looping constructs in detail to understand this. 'Break' statement works only with loops and switch statements. You cannot even add 'break' within 'if clause' outside the looping construct.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the expected result. `break` breaks loops, not `if else` clauses. If
the code gets to the point where it prints `NOW WILL BREAK AND NO SAVE` it will never
try the remaining `else` clauses.

Perhaps you are looking for `continue` ? It will break only the current iteration of
the loop. -edit- However, it's completely unnecessary in your case.